# Is there a way to run cucumber scenarios in parallel

Tags: ruby, parallel-processing, cucumber

I am using Ruby and cucumber to run my end-to end tests . I have lots of tests which take longer time to run . I am using 'parallel_tests' to run my 'features' in parallel which has minimised the execution time significantly  .But I wanted to know if there is a way to run 'scenarios' in parallel

Answer (score 2):

Yes! There is.

Using the cukeforker library you can run either features or scenarios in parallel.

https://github.com/jarib/cukeforker

```
# parallelize per scenario, with one JUnit XML file per scenario.
CukeForker::Runner.run CukeForker::Scenarios.tagged(%W[@edition ~@wip])
                       :extra_args => %W[-f CukeForker::Formatters::JunitScenarioFormatter --out results/junit]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question , I will give it a try

Comment: As I see JUnit in it, is this only for Java, or ruby as well. How do I install? How does it work? The README is rather short. Thank you for the hint and any help